# Whats the difference between these two java code snippets?

Tags: java

I have this code i am doing for university. The first code works as expected, the second one provides different results.

I can not see what they are doing differently??

first:

```
public Mat3 getNormalMatrix() {
    return new Mat3(this.getInverseMatrix()).transpose();
}
```

second:

```
public Mat3 getNormalMatrix() {
    Mat4 mat = this.getInverseMatrix();
    Mat3 bla = new Mat3(mat);
    bla.transpose();
    return bla;
}
```

Comment: What is the declared return type of getInverseMatrix()?

Comment: What is the different result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one returns the result of transpose() the second one returns bla.

In the second example, you want

```
bla = bla.transpose();
```

Comment: To elaborate a bit on this. I believe the point is that transpose returns a different instance of Mat3, as opposed to modifying the instance it's called upon. I'm just guessing, but the Mat3 class may be immutable.

Comment: lol thanks, i am so dumb blind xD. i think i will print this page out and hange it out on my toilet so i get reminded all the tim :D